# Showing two factors to be coprime

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am working on this problem

> Assume $x,y,z$ are integers which satisfy:$$x^2+2y^2=z^2$$
>   where $x$ and $y$ are coprime and $z$ is odd. 
> Factorize $x^2+2y^2$ in $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$ and show that the factors are coprime.

I have factorized as $x^2+2y^2=(x+y\sqrt{-2})(x-y\sqrt{-2})$

From here I know that I need to let $d$ be a common factor of $(x+y\sqrt{-2})$ and $(x-y\sqrt{-2})$ and then show that $d$ is a unit by showing that $N(d)=1$

However I am unsure how my assumptoins help me here

Comment: Are the factors to be shown coprime in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$ or in some other sense?

Comment: in $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the fact that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$ is Euclidean, hence is a PID: Let $\pi$ be a prime in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$. If $\pi$ divides both $x+\sqrt{-2}y$ and $x-\sqrt{-2}y$, then it divides $x+\sqrt{-2}y+(x-\sqrt{-2}y)=2x$. Similarly, it divides $x+\sqrt{-2}y-(x-\sqrt{-2}y)=2\sqrt{-2}y$.

Therefore $\pi$ divides the gcd of $2x$ and $2\sqrt{-2}y$, which is 2 since $x$ and $y$ are coprime. But $\pi^2$ divides $z$, so this contradicts the fact that $z$ is odd.

Comment: I am unsure what to conclude from the contradiction

Comment: If you make an assumption which leads to a contradiction, then the assumption must be false. In this case the assumption was that $x+\sqrt{-2}y$ and $x-\sqrt{-2}y$ have a prime factor in common.